# hMail can't send between two machines running under one domain

Tags: windows

Consider I have 2 different machines with hmail installed. Both pointing to different MX record but in one domain.

> domain.com -> mx:1.1.1.1 -> hmail server1
>
> domain.com -> mx:2.2.2.2 -> hmail server2

I have successfully configured both mail server and client and I have no problem sending and receiving external mails. The problem is that I can't send email from between the two. Example I have account registered to each server am I missing a configuration or something?

> hmail server1 -> admin@domain.com
>
> hmail server2 -> client@domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Each server is independently authoritative for the domain you configured. They don't "share" the domain. You can't natively send email to users on one server from the other server. You need to see if hMailServer supports SMTP namespace sharing if you want to have the same domain on each server and want to have user mailboxes on both servers.